# Does far infrared penetrate smoke better than near ir?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, infrared-radiation

I assume it would, but the EU's Sentinel-2 satellite uses near-ir instead....

Just wondering why.... And which wavelengths penetrate smoke (not fog) the best....

Answer (score 1):

Sentinel 2 has three sensor ranges -- visual, near IR, and Short Wave IR.  Yes, the near IR is affected by smoke, and this will degrade its image quality near forest fires.  But the SW IR penetrates smoke and will give ground data even near forest fires.  While the LW IR would provide slightly better smoke penetration than even SW IR, LW IR gives lower resolution accuracy.  As the primary purpose of Sentinel 2 is high resolution vegetation mapping, not fire tracking, the SW IR is the more useful frequency to carry.  See page 51 of this reference, to see the effect of hydrocarbon (HC) smoke on these four frequencies.  https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a050370.pdf  See this reference for the missions of Sentinel 2.  https://www.satimagingcorp.com/satellite-sensors/other-satellite-sensors/sentinel-2a/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dcleve!  Truly helpful....

Comment: Glad to help!  If this ends up being the best and a complete answer, you can give it a check as well.